# How to prevent a binary search tree from getting to large ?

Tags: data-structures

this concept would be really easy if I were using something like an array. For instance the pseudocode would be something like:

```
if array.count > 20000 {
 delete unwanted element and append new value
} else {
  append value to array 
}
```

However, when it comes to binary trees getting the count kills my CPU / memory. It makes sense as to why, but I was wondering  if someone had an alternative way of keeping a binary tree from getting too big? 
Note: Keeping track of how many times the insert function gets called wouldn't work since duplicate values are discarded... 
Hope this made sense.... Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't see why you can't keep a count of the inserted nodes; there's some point when you know you're actually inserting or discarding.

Comment: You can update the count when you actually insert the item, rather than when you call the insert function. Or, if you want to keep the count outside the tree, have the insert function return true when an item is actually inserted, and return false if it's a duplicate item that's been discarded.